# creating a runnble jar with lwjgl

Tags: jar, lwjgl

I made a game using LWJGL and i need to be able to open it with a runnble jar.
the game contain another jar of program i made that let you build maps for the game so in the
game i can click on a button and the builder opens.

i tried to use jarsplice and i managed to open the jar of my game and see the main menu
however when i click on the button that open the game itself or the map builder the program 
just crushed..

I have no idea what to do.... hope you can help me with that.
thanks.

Comment: Jarsplice really is great, I would recommend watching a tutorial and follow every step to the letter.

Comment: I did, and managed to make a jar however it doesn't work well

Answer (score 0):

Okay it looks like you need to debug the problem.  Here is how I would do it:

1. Make the runnable fat jar using jarsplice
2. Put it in a new folder
3. Also in that folder create a file called `run.bat`
4. Edit `run.bat` with notepad++ (or another text editor) and paste this code into it

   java -jar jarname.jar
   PAUSE
5. Obviously replace jarname.jar with the name of your fat jar

Now when you run `run.bat` and you trigger the error you should be able to see the stack trace!  If you can't solve the problem from that then post it here and I'll have a go at it.

Sorry that this isn't actually an answer, but it would be too hard to read if it was a comment.

Comment: When im trying making the fat jar im doing just like the tutorials in the internet, I'm making runnble jar and a lib folder that contain all the jars. when im using the jarsplice and trying to make the fat jar it says: " Jar creation failed due to the following exception:       duplicate entry: .classpath". what do you think is the problem?

Comment: From eclipse, export as a jar, not a runnable jar

Comment: And if that doesn't solve it, open up your jar with winRAR or 7zip and delete .classpath

Comment: When I click on export to jar there are 4 options to choose from..   What should I choose?

Comment: Export generated class files and resources

Comment: i deleted the .classpath from the game jar and yet it dosnt let me create the fat jar. it keep says "duplicate entry: .classpath"